# How did they convert IR-Lock pixels to a position on a normal plane 1m in front of the lens

Tags: c++, math, image-processing

I am working on tracking a moving target using Quadcopter. In my project, I am using an IR-Camera which is a modified version of the Pixy camera, but for detecting IR targets. While I was studying their code I found a part where I couldn't understand it. I tried googling it but didn't find anything or any formula related to it. So I wonder if someone can give me some tips on what equations or formula they used.

Here is the part I didn't understand.

```
/*
converts IRLOCK pixels to a position on a normal plane 1m in front of the lens based 
on a characterization of IR-LOCK with the standard lens, focused such that 2.38mm 
of threads are exposed 
*/
void AP_IRLock_I2C::pixel_to_1M_plane(float pix_x, float pix_y, float &ret_x, float &ret_y)
{
ret_x = (-0.00293875727162397f*pix_x + 0.470201163459835f)/
(4.43013552642296e-6f*((pix_x - 160.0f)*(pix_x - 160.0f)) 
+ 4.79331390531725e-6f*((pix_y - 100.0f)*(pix_y - 100.0f)) - 1.0f);
ret_y = (-0.003056843086277f*pix_y + 0.3056843086277f)/
(4.43013552642296e-6f*((pix_x - 160.0f)*(pix_x - 160.0f)) 
+ 4.79331390531725e-6f*((pix_y - 100.0f)*(pix_y - 100.0f)) - 1.0f);
```

You can find the rest of the code here. 
[IRlock Ardupilot](https://github.com/ArduPilot/ardupilot/blob/master/libraries/AP_IRLock/AP_IRLock_I2C.cpp)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's focus on the equation for `ret_x`, which simplified is like this:

```
ret_x = (-0.0029 * pix_x + 0.47) /
        (4.4e-6 * (pix_x - 160.0)^2 + 4.8e-6 * (pix_y - 100.0)^2 - 1.0);
```

First, notice the 160 and 100 magic numbers.  The Pixy capture resolution is 320x200, so these are there to translate pixel coordinates from a space where (0,0) is in the corner to where it is in the center.  So if `pix_x` is 160 and `pix_y` is 100, that is the center of the frame, and the denominator will be -1.

The rest of it appears to be a lens correction.  Here are the values of `ret_x` that you get across the range of valid `pix_x` and `pix_y` inputs:

```
        0      40      80     120    160     200     240     280     320
  0 -0.56   -0.40   -0.25   -0.12   0.00    0.12    0.25    0.40    0.56
 20 -0.55   -0.39   -0.25   -0.12   0.00    0.12    0.25    0.39    0.55
 40 -0.54   -0.38   -0.25   -0.12   0.00    0.12    0.25    0.38    0.54
 60 -0.53   -0.38   -0.24   -0.12   0.00    0.12    0.24    0.38    0.53
 80 -0.53   -0.38   -0.24   -0.12   0.00    0.12    0.24    0.38    0.53
100 -0.53   -0.38   -0.24   -0.12   0.00    0.12    0.24    0.38    0.53
120 -0.53   -0.38   -0.24   -0.12   0.00    0.12    0.24    0.38    0.53
140 -0.53   -0.38   -0.24   -0.12   0.00    0.12    0.24    0.38    0.53
160 -0.54   -0.38   -0.25   -0.12   0.00    0.12    0.25    0.38    0.54
180 -0.55   -0.39   -0.25   -0.12   0.00    0.12    0.25    0.39    0.55
200 -0.56   -0.40   -0.25   -0.12   0.00    0.12    0.25    0.40    0.56
```

So as expected, `ret_x` is near 0 for pixels near the center (`pix_x == 160`).  And it reaches +/- 0.56 at the extremes, which suggests a horizontal field of view of approximately 120 degrees (from trigonometry, 2*0.56 meter width at 1 meter distance).

The horizontal correction is slightly influenced by the vertical coordinate, notably near the corners.  This is presumably to correct for spherical distortion in the lens (which is common).

The astute will recognize that the equation is slightly defective: given pixel coordinates in [0,319] and [0,199], the center values should be 159.5 and 99.5, not 160 and 100.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Now its clear what they did.

Comment: @MohamedRabah: You're welcome.  I didn't have any prior knowledge of this code or camera.  I just used some background knowledge of digital photography, trigonometry, the camera specs, and a spreadsheet.

Comment: Sure, I was just looking for it.

Comment: I can't upvote your answer now, because I have only 11 reputation. Sorry for this.